# Newbie question about controller and request in Laravel in my case

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am new in Laravel, what I try to achieve is very simple thing, I would like to use `FormRequest` provided by Laravel to do validation of the request, but I encounter some puzzles (which I am sure is easy things to solve if you are experienced in Laravel).

Here is what I tried:

I have route maps to controller:

```
Route::put('user/{name}', 'UserController@show');
```

I can get the `name` parameter in `show` function:

```
class UserController {
  public function show($name)
  {
     // validtion rules to apply
    ...
  }
}
```

I have validation rules to apply to the request, so I decided to create form request by `php artisan make:request ShowRequest`, which creates the form request class:

```
class ShowRequest extends FormRequest {
  public function authorize()
  {
     return true;
  }

  public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // my validation rules here
        ];
    }
}
```

Since I have above request class, so I refactored the `show` function in controller to receive the `ShowRequest` .

```
class UserController {
  public function show(ShowRequest $request)
  {
     // now I don't need validtion rules in this function 
     // but how can I access the 'name' parameter now
    ...
  }
}
```

I have two questions to ask:

1. Inside the refactored `show` function, how can I now access the route parameter `name` ?
2. If we forget about the parameter is a name (please don't focus on what to validate for name, imaging it is an object or value to validate in general). How to add custom logic for handling validation error instead of using Laravel default behaviour. I want to inject code like dummy code below:

```
if (!$validator->pass()) 
{ 
  //my custom code for handling validation failure
}
```

Where to put my custom code for handling validation error now? I mean I don't know where to have this logic, in controller? in the request class? how?

Comment: for 1. add name after request `public function show(ShowRequest $request, $name)`, for 2. can you explain more with an example

Comment: Which _form_ data do you want to validate here? Does `$name` come from a form? Or do you just want to make sure `$name` doesn't contain any special characters?

Comment: If you only think `$name` as an example to illustrate the question I have, please don't focusing on what to validate for a name. It could be whatever parameter I pass in, question is the same.

Comment: I updated my 2nd question now.

Answer (score 2):

You still can add the parameter `$name` in the `show()` method of your controller as it's part of the routed url more than the validated form/data. (recommanded)

```
class UserController {
    public function show(ShowRequest $request, $name)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can also access it from the request object

```
class UserController {
    public function show(ShowRequest $request)
    {
        $request->input('name');
    }
}
```

As for the error messages (not the exception) you can add the `messages()` method to your `ShowRequest::class`

```
class ShowRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'The name is required',
            'name.numeric' => 'The name must be a number',
            //...
        ];
    }
}
```

If you instead need to validate that the name catched by the route is only composed of letter OR really exists as a field in your DB (like a slug of a post) you need to add some validation in your route declaration.

1. Setup a route that catches request only if it is composed of letters.

```
Route::get('/user/{name}', 'Controller@show')->where(['name' => '[a-z]+']);
```

2. Setup a route that catches request only if the "name" exists in DB:

**User.php**

```
Class User //..
{
    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'name';
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
//
Route::get('/user/{user:name}', 'Controller@show');
```

And adapt your controller to take a user directly

```
class UserController {
    public function show(ShowRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: If the request is not from a form on UI, but from a API call by another service, does the answer still apply?

Comment: If we forget about the parameter is a name, but anything.  My main point of my 2nd question is how to add custom logic for handling validation error instead of using Laravel default behaviour.  I want to inject code like `if (!$validator->pass()) { my custom code for handling validation failure}`. How to do that with current setup? I updated my post for my 2nd question now. Thanks.

Comment: @user842225 the answer to your first question is YES, it's the same any request, no matter the origin of the request. the answer (format) depends on the accept header of the request (accept:application/json in API case sent by the client)

Comment: @user842225 as for the second point, if you want a json response instead of the html for an api call, just add the header in your request. for example with `curl` you add `-H "accept: application/json"` with postman, add a header. if you want to intercept any error by FormRequest wich triggers a `ValidationException::class` exception, intercept it in the `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` of your laravel installation in the render method (for example)

Comment: Thanks, actually the comments discussion with @Rehan (see the other answer post) answered my 2nd question. Now I feel combine both yours and his answer is the correct overall answer to my question, I am not sure which one to accept :D

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of the Form Request using this

`$validated = $request->validated();`

The $validated will have all the values which had been validated by the FormRequest.

To answer your second question, if you want to throw custom validation, you can always use the following

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages(['name' => 'Something is wrong']);
```

Comment: In where should I put that throw code?

Comment: In the controller.

Comment: thanks. I updated my post for clarifying my 2nd question better. Looking forward to your answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don;t undestand what you are trying to achieve in here. If you use FormRequest, and if the validation fails, the request life cycle dies and do not continue to controller.  Maybe you are looking for something like this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#after-validation-hook

Comment: exactly that! But the link you send gives sample code in controller I guess, since now my validation logic is in the FormRequest, I wonder how to have that after-validation-hook now with my current code?

Comment: This is the equivalent for FormRequest: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#adding-after-hooks-to-form-requests

Comment: thanks! That is what I need. About your answer to my 1st question, you mentioned `$validated` contains the `name` value. Do you mean I can access the `name` route parameter by `$validated->name` ? If so, could you please update your answer to be more clear?